# SHA512 hash to string in C#

Tags: c#, string, hash, sha512

I have code to generate SHA512 from string.

```
 public static string GetCrypt(string text)
        {
            string hash = "";
            SHA512 alg = SHA512.Create();
            byte[] result = alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
            hash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
            return hash;
        }
```

Now I must convert hash back to string. Any ideas how can it be done? Thank you.

Comment: This can't be done. A hash function is one way.

Comment: What you want is encryption. There's an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider) on how to use AES to do just that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hashes are 1-way. You can't get it back (easily). you might want actual encryption.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas how encrypt and decrypt data in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Hashes are one-way. Please use symmetric encryption classes like RijndaelManaged.

Here is a RijndaelSimple class that I am using:
http://www.obviex.com/samples/encryption.asp

The cached version of the same link is here:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WyVau-XgIzkJ:www.obviex.com/samples/encryption.asp&hl=en&prmd=imvns&strip=1

Answer (score 0):

You cant convert a `hash` back to string from which you computed the hash.

If you want it then you would have to **compare** the hash with each of the target strings hash.

If one of them matches with the hash,then that hash comes from the target string.

**Its use:** If you want to store `passwords` in `database`,you can store its hashes instead of passwords.So even if a hacker gets access to your database,he cant get the password cuz it is hashed.The only way to know the string through which we created the hash is to **match** it with the desired string!